# EF 4.0 with oracle

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, entity-framework-4

I want in VisaulStudio 2010 Use EF 4.0 with oracle.

I install visual studio and oracle 9g.

when add item => ADO.NET entity data model and new connection =>Datasource : dont any oracle server.

need I installl ODAC (oracle client)?

whats need  other things?

tanx a lot